# React, form input stops working after opening and closing custom drop down

Tags: reactjs

I have created a form with a custom drop down component, and I've spent the day trying to find out what is causing this.

I've tried using `useRef` and use `defaultValue` SO answers.

The 'Menu Name' text input can be changed multiple times **until I click my `<DropDownComponent/>`**.

After I selected a few days, and close the popup, my input becomes unusable.

[Availability Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khUfE.png)

[After opening and closing the popup, I lose the ability to interact with the text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUl2.png)

Why is this happening? I feel like `<input onChange=()=>{}/>` is somehow being lost on the DOM possibly?

**MenuForm.tsx**

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect,  useState } from "react";
import { .......... } from '../../../styling/styled-components';
import DropDownComponent from "../../UI/DropDownComponent/DropDownComponent";
import useImgUpload from "../../../hooks/useImgUpload";
import Icon from "../../../assets/icons/Icons";

const MenuForm = () => {
  const {imgUrl, uploadFn} = useImgUpload();
  const INPUT_LIST = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
  const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [availableDays, setAvailableDays ] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(availableDays);
  },[availableDays])

  const anyTimeCheckBox = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    console.log(event.target.id);
  }

  const showUploadedImg = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event);
    uploadFn(event);
  }

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`${nameInput}, ${availableDays}`);
  }

  const selectedDayHandler = (arr:string[]) => {
    setAvailableDays( arr );
    console.log('Days Set');
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setNameInput((currState:string) => {return currState = e.target.value});
  }

  console.log('Menu Form rendered');

  return(
    <MenuFormStyle onSubmit={submitHandler}>

      <MenuImgWrapper>
        <ImgInput
          type='file'
          alt='Add Image'
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  
          onChange={showUploadedImg}
        />
        <ImgDisplay>
          <LoadedImgCont>
            {
              imgUrl 
              ?
              <LoadedImg src={imgUrl} alt='uploaded-img'></LoadedImg>
              : 
              <>
                <NoImg src={Icon.AddImage} alt='icon-placeholder'></NoImg>
                <NoImgTxt>Add Image</NoImgTxt>
              </>
            }
          </LoadedImgCont>
        </ImgDisplay>
        
      </MenuImgWrapper>

      <MenuNameInput
        type='text' 
        placeholder= 'Menu name'
        name='menuName'
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        defaultValue={nameInput}
      />

      {/* Day + Time selections */}
      <DropDownComponent list={INPUT_LIST} setSelectedDays={selectedDayHandler}/>
      
      <TimeStartInput
        type='time'
        placeholder='Start'
      />

      <TimeEndInput 
        type='time'
        placeholder="End"
      />

      <TimeCheckBoxWpr>
        <TimeCheckBox
          type='checkbox'
          name='24/7'
          id='isAlwaysAvailable'
          onChange={anyTimeCheckBox}/>
        <label htmlFor='24/7'>Anytime</label>
      </TimeCheckBoxWpr>

      {/*Extra Settings */}
      <FieldSetMenu>
        <legend>Menu Settings:</legend>
        <div>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            name='apples'
            id='apples'
            />
            <label htmlFor='apples'>Hide menu</label>
        </div>
      </FieldSetMenu>

      <MenuSaveButton>Save</MenuSaveButton>

    </MenuFormStyle>
  );
}

export default MenuForm;
```

**DropDownComponent**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Icon from "../../../assets/icons/Icons";

import {
  ArrowDownIcon,
  CloseIcon,
  CustomListItem,
  DaySelectInput,
  DaySelectPopUp,
  DisplaySelectedDays,
  SelectedText,
  UList,
} from "../../../styling/styled-components";

interface IProps {
  list: string[];
  setSelectedDays: (arr: string[]) => void;
  multiSelect?: boolean;
}

interface ListProps {
  list: DropDownProps[];
  updateSelection: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
  closeDropDown: () => void;
}

interface DropDownProps {
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

const DropDownComponent = (props: IProps) => {
  const [displayDropDown, setDisplayDropDown] = useState(false);
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [customListItems, setCustomListItems] = useState<DropDownProps[]>();
  const { list, setSelectedDays } = props;

  useMemo(() => {
    let buildListArray: DropDownProps[] = list.reduce(
      (previous, current) => [...previous, { value: current, selected: false }],
      [{ value: "Reset", selected: false }]
    );
    setCustomListItems((currState) => {
      return (currState = buildListArray);
    });
    console.log("DropDownComponent");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedDays(selectedItems);
  },[selectedItems, setSelectedDays]);

  const captureSelected = (event: any) => {
    //updates state of custom drop down menu

    let dropDownItem = customListItems![event.target.value];
    dropDownItem.selected = !dropDownItem.selected;
    let updatedSelectState = dropDownItem.selected;

    if (updatedSelectState && dropDownItem.value === "Reset") {
      console.log('Reset Triggered');
      setSelectedItems([]);
      customListItems?.forEach((item) => {
        item.selected = false;
      });
      return;
    } else if (updatedSelectState && !existsInList()) {
      console.log('Added to SelectedItems');
      setSelectedItems((currState) => {
        return [...currState, dropDownItem.value];
      });
    } else if (!updatedSelectState && existsInList()) {
      console.log('Removed from selected items');
      let updatedArray = selectedItems.filter(
        (item) => item !== dropDownItem.value
      );
      setSelectedItems(updatedArray);
    }

    function existsInList(): boolean {
      return selectedItems.includes(dropDownItem.value);
    }
  };

  const displaySelection = (items: string[]): string => {
    return items.join(", ");
  };

  const toggleDropDown = () => {
    console.log(selectedItems);
    setDisplayDropDown(currState => !currState);
    console.log('toggle');
  };

  return (
    <DaySelectInput>
      <DisplaySelectedDays>
        <SelectedText>
          { 
            !selectedItems.length 
            ? 
            "Availability" 
            : 
            displaySelection(selectedItems) 
          }
        </SelectedText>

        {
          displayDropDown 
          ? 
          <CloseIcon src={Icon.Close} alt='dummy-icon'/>
          :
          <ArrowDownIcon 
            src={ Icon.ArrowDown } 
            alt='icon-down' 
            onClick={toggleDropDown}
            />
        }
        
        </DisplaySelectedDays>

        {
          displayDropDown 
          && 
          <DropDownList
              list={customListItems!}
              updateSelection={captureSelected}
              closeDropDown={toggleDropDown}
          />
        }
    </DaySelectInput>
  );
};

const DropDownList = (props: ListProps) => {
  const elRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const { list, closeDropDown } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ClickOutside Effect')
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };

    function handleClickOutside(event: any) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (elRef.current && !elRef.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        closeDropDown();
      }
    }
  }, [elRef, closeDropDown]);

  return (
    <DaySelectPopUp ref={elRef}>
      <UList>
        {list?.map((listItem: DropDownProps, index:number) => {
          return (
            <CustomListItem
              key={`li-${listItem.value}`}
              value={index}
              onClick={props.updateSelection}
              userSelected={listItem.selected}
            >
              {listItem.value}
            </CustomListItem>
          );
        })}
      </UList>
    </DaySelectPopUp>
  );
};
export default DropDownComponent;
```

**styled components file incase you want to try for yourself**

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';

const primaryMain = '#003332';
const primaryLight = '#305d5b';
const primaryDark = '#000e0a';

const baseBackground = '#EBE9E9';

const secondaryMain = '#003332';
const secondaryLight = '#305d5b';
const secondaryDark = '#000e0a';

const textLight = 'white';
const textDark = 'black';

//Texts
const StandardText = styled.p` 
  color: ${textLight};
`;

//UI
const BaseCard = styled.div` 
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: ${baseBackground};
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 5px;
`;

const GreenCard = styled(BaseCard)`
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: ${primaryMain};
`

//NavigationComponent
const NavBackDrop = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background: ${primaryDark};
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
`;
const NavWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background: ${primaryMain};
  padding: 5px 0px;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const NavLogoWrapper = styled.div` 
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background: ${primaryLight};
  margin-left: 10px;
`;

const NavLinkWrapper = styled.div` 
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;

  & > a {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  & > a.active {
    background: ${primaryLight};
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 100px;

    & > p {
      color: white;
      font-weight: 700;
      transform: scale(1.05);
      margin: 10px 0px;
    }
  }

`;

const ProfileImgWrapper = styled.div` 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: ${primaryLight};
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
`;

const DashBoardGrid = styled.div` 
  min-height: 80vh;
  height: fit-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30vw 30vw 35vw;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;

  & > div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #00000038;
  }
`;

const DashSalesGridWrapper = styled(BaseCard)` 
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
`;

const DashMenuWrapper = styled(BaseCard)` 
  grid-column: 3 ;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
`;

const DashKpiWrapper = styled(BaseCard)`
  grid-column: 1 / span 2 ;
  grid-row: 2 ;
`;

const MenuWrapper = styled.div` 
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
`

const Grid = styled(BaseCard)` 
  width: 45vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  align-items: flex-start;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #00000054;
`;

const CreateNewButton = styled.button`
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid ${primaryLight};
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  &:hover{
    transform: scale(1.01);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #00000054;
    font-size: 0.9rem;

    &>img{
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
  }
`;

const IconImg = styled.img`
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
`;

const CustomListItem = styled.li<{userSelected:boolean}>`
  color: ${ props =>  props.userSelected ? 'white': 'none'};
  background: ${ props =>  props.userSelected ? primaryLight : 'none'};
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 28%;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid ${primaryLight};
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;

  &:first-of-type {
    width: 100%;
  }

  &:hover{
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
`;

const DaySelectInput = styled.div` 
  grid-column: 3/ span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  position: relative;
`;

const DaySelectPopUp = styled.div` 
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #d6d9d9;
  border: 2px solid ${primaryLight};
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
`;

const UList = styled.ul` 
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
`;

const MenuFormStyle = styled.form` 
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    grid-template-columns: 27% 27% 20% 20%;
    grid-gap: 5px;

    color: #444;
    border: 3px solid #305d5b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  `;

  const MenuImgWrapper = styled.div` 
    grid-column: 1/span 2;
    grid-row: 1/ span 2;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
  `;

  const ImgInput = styled.input` 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
  `;

  const ImgDisplay = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border: 3px solid #003332;
    background: #d6d9d9;
  `;

  const MenuNameInput = styled.input` 
    grid-column: 3/span 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid ${primaryLight};
  `;

  const TimeStartInput = styled.input` 
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  `;
  const TimeEndInput = styled.input` 
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 3;
`;

  const TimeCheckBox = styled.input` 
    border-radius: 50%;
  `;

  const TimeCheckBoxWpr = styled.div` 
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: fit-content;
  `;

  const FieldSetMenu = styled.fieldset` 
    grid-row: 5/span 2;
    grid-column: 1/span 4;
  `;

  const MenuSaveButton = styled.button` 
    grid-row: 9;
    grid-column: 4;
  `;

  const DisplaySelectedDays = styled.div` 
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid ${primaryLight};
    padding: 5px;
  `;

  const SelectedText = styled.span` 
    margin: 0px;
  `;

  const LoadedImg = styled.img` 
    width: 80%;
    height:auto;
  `;

  const NoImg = styled(LoadedImg)`
    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  `;

  const NoImgTxt = styled.p` 
    font-size: 20px;
  `;

  const LoadedImgCont = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  `;

  const ArrowDownIcon = styled.img` 
    cursor: hover;
    float: right;
    width: fit-content;
  `;

  const CloseIcon = styled(ArrowDownIcon)``;



export {
  ArrowDownIcon,
  BaseCard,
  CloseIcon,
  CreateNewButton,
  CustomListItem,
  DashBoardGrid,
  DashKpiWrapper,
  DashMenuWrapper,
  DashSalesGridWrapper,
  DaySelectInput,
  DaySelectPopUp,
  DisplaySelectedDays,
  FieldSetMenu,
  GreenCard,
  Grid,
  IconImg,
  ImgInput,
  ImgDisplay,
  LoadedImg,
  LoadedImgCont,
  MenuFormStyle,
  MenuImgWrapper,
  MenuNameInput,
  MenuSaveButton,
  MenuWrapper,
  NavBackDrop,
  NavWrapper,
  NavLogoWrapper,
  NavLinkWrapper,
  NoImg,
  NoImgTxt,
  ProfileImgWrapper,
  SelectedText,
  StandardText,
  TimeCheckBoxWpr,
  TimeEndInput,
  TimeStartInput,
  TimeCheckBox,
  UList,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DropDownList` you register some click outside listeners, but this happens in a `useMemo` when it should be a `useEffect`. Therefore the click handler is never removed when the popup closes which probably makes everything unselectable as `preventDefault` is called on every click.

Comment: good point, thank you Adam. Will change that now.

Comment: That worked! Wow, I have a lot to learn. I would have never gotten that. Thanks Adam.
So, trying to understand this better. Echoing what you said, and correct me if i'm wrong. The event listener 'hijacks' the mouse click event, until it's removed. Because I usedMemo, it memoized and cached that block of code, even when the component was removed from the DOM?

Comment: @rarara No worries -- it took me 10+ years to get here haha! Would you mind marking as accepted :)

Comment: Yeh thats what happening. Basically it register a click handler that captures all mouse clicks but then it never gets cleaned up again. The reason it sticks around though is not because its memoized.

When you register a global even handler, react does not know how to get rid of it when the component unmounts, you have to manually detach it. useEffect allows you to return a function that is run on unmount. useMemo has no such thing so that inner function that was doing the detaching was never called.