# What is different btw useState<string[]>([]); and useState([]);

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state, react-state

I was browing stackoverflow while looking for the question that I can answer and I came accross this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994491/react-form-input-stops-working-after-opening-and-closing-custom-drop-down)

This person use something like

```
  const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [availableDays, setAvailableDays ] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

and I normally use

```
  const [nameInput,setNameInput] = useState('');
  const [availableDays,setAvailableDays] = useState([]);
```

and sometimes this

```
  import * as React form 'react';
  const [nameInput,setNameInput] = React.useState('');
  const [availableDays,setAvailableDays] = React.useState([]);
```

so which is better?

Comment: It's TypeScript vs JavaScript. Depends what you want to use.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please specify in _objective_ terms what _you_ mean by "better" or this is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typeScript

```
// the state can hold a value with type string
const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState<string>('');

// the state can hold an array of strings
 const [availableDays, setAvailableDays ] = useState<string[]>([])
```

if you try to put an integer into one of them, it will give you an error. IMO, typescript is better since it mitigates the chance of passing values that shouldn't be passed

Comment: Read up on typescript here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/